# Run the Selenium Test inside EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver, amazon-eks

I'm have java code, and trying to make containerized application and deploy the workload into EKS cluster 1.24 with managed node group.

I have created docker image and deployed into k8s cluster,  But when i'm see the pod is not coming up whit CrashLoopBackOff.

I have mounted the volume in one of worker node where i can see index.html file with below error log about my test case execution.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4444
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:242)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
```

Adding Additional note here, k8s-deployment.yaml file.
I have deployed Selenium Grid service and exposed the service using alb ingress controller, and i can able to access selenium grid Hub with single node chrome installed using external URL which provided AWS.

```
kubectl get ingress
http://internal-k8s-devops-path-of-the-adddress
```

### NOTE

k8s_host: my-alb-ingress-address
selenium_grid_host: my-grid-hub-service-name:4444
MODULE: search-module.xml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler-deployment
  namespace: devops-java-selenium
  labels:
    app: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler
    name: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler
        name: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: selenium-grid-k8s-autoscaler
          image: my-app-image
          env:
            - name: k8s_host
              value: my-alb-ingress-address
            - name: selenium_grid_host
              value: selenium-grid-hub:4444
            - name: MODULE
              value: search-module.xml
          volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /usr/share/selenium/test-output
                name: devops-java-selenium-pv
      volumes:
        - name: devops-java-selenium-pv
          hostPath:
             path: /tmp/app
```

application deployment pod logs

```
Jul 10, 2023 6:16:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Jul 10, 2023 6:16:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Jul 10, 2023 6:16:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Jul 10, 2023 6:16:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`

===============================================
search-module
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 4
Configuration Failures: 4, Skips: 4
===============================================
```

can you please some one help me on this.